# Jquery binding to keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some problems binding to the keyup event of a textarea control. I'm trying the below

```
var shortDescInput = $('nobr:contains("Short Description")').closest('tr').find($('textarea[title="Short Description"]'));

    // this doesn't work
    shortDescInput.bind('keyup', function () {
        countShortDescChars();
    });

    // Nor this
    shortDescInput.keyup(function () {
        countShortDescChars();
    });
```

Am I missing something here that's really obvious? This is working for other controls, for example binding events to radiobuttons. I've checked and I'm defiantly selecting the right textarea with

```
var shortDescInput = $('nobr:contains("Short Description")').closest('tr').find($('textarea[title="Short Description"]'));
```

I just never seem to get the keyup event....

Comment: Can you set up a demo on http://jsfiddle.net ? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, ok, this is a bit of a mess but it's the rough idea of what's going on... [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kNkXE/3/)

Comment: Please note that somewhat stupidly I just took an extract of the table I was dealing with for the JSfiddle link above, so the table is in actually fact correctly formed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find($('textarea[title="Short Description"]'))` is highly inefficient. For your purposes, `find` should take a selector as it's argument.

When you pass in a jQuery object to `find`, jQuery first queries the DOM from the top and finds all elements that match that selector. Then, `find` loops through **all** of these results until it finds one that matches the specified parents.

You should, instead, use:

```
find('textarea[title="Short Description"]')
```

Also, use `.on` instead of `.bind`. `.bind` is set to be deprecated in future releases for it's inefficiency.

```
shortDescInput.on("keyup", countShortDescChars);
```

And the revised code:

```
$(function () {
    var shortDescInput = $('nobr:contains("Short Description")').closest('tr').find('textarea[title="Short Description"]');

    shortDescInput.on("keyup", countShortDescChars);
});
```

Comment: `find` also takes a jQuery object: http://api.jquery.com/find/ (yeah, I was surprised too)

Comment: In this case it is much less efficient to use a jQuery object.

Comment: Yes, true (comment too short)

Comment: Thanks guys, I've altered the selector (I've confirmed the old one was working though) that didn't fix things ... Also tried .on instead of .bind and that isn't helping either. All very strange!

Comment: I don't know if this might be relevant but this is in a SharePoint environment with a ListFieldIterator spitting out the controls onto the page. I wouldn't think that it should be stopping anything from working however as I've bound to other events with no problems on different controls

Comment: You must encapsulate all of this jQuery within `$(function() { ... your code here ... })`

Comment: Austin - nope...given that a whirl (I presume you mean encapsulating the binding?) and no improvement.

Comment: The declaration and the `on`. See my revised answer.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean - thanks for the revised answer. Nope also given that a go and no change. This is somewhat mystifying.

Comment: In the end several colleagues and I attacked this problem for a while and it looks like sharepoint is interfering with this. Marking this as correct as it should have worked. Thanks for pointing out a more efficient selector and more up-to-date way of binding to the event.

Answer (score 0):

To verify that a selector is working **use .length** with a console.log() or old fashioned alert() :

```
var shortDescInput = $('nobr:contains("Short Description")').closest('tr').find('textarea[title="Short Description"]');

alert(shortDescInput.length);
```

You can also go step by step to identify the one not returning anything :

```
alert($('nobr:contains("Short Description")').length);
alert($('nobr:contains("Short Description")').closest('tr').length);
alert($('nobr:contains("Short Description")').closest('tr').find('textarea[title="Short Description"]').length);
```

Second try. **using .on() instead of .bind()** :

```
shortDescInput.on('keyup',function(){countShortDescChars();});
```

Comment: Hi, I can verify the selector is working, I run the countShortDescChars(); on pageload and the element I expect gets set with the length of that field. I also added in alert(shortDescInput.val().length); and also get an alert with the right text

Comment: Ok, good news! Let's try another way, I updated my answer with .on()

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, guys above have also suggested the same and that's not resulted in it working either strangely.

Comment: Have you tried with "click" instead of "keyup"? I remember some weird stories with keyup never being triggered on a dynamically created textarea, while all other events where working just fine.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same thing! Tried with Click just to test and not getting that either

Comment: Maybe not related but.. how about changing your <nobr> to a CSS white-space:nowrap; ? Have you tried taking your textarea at the root of <body>?

Answer (score 0):

So I played along with your fiddle and...
**There IS something wrong with your selector.**

- First I remove the script tags from the js part.
- then remove the script tag in your html cause it broke the fiddle.
- Switched to jQuery 1.8.0 cause MooTools is not what we want.
- added `shortDescInput = $('textarea');` after your giant selector, **event is triggered!**
- Added again `shortDescInput = $('textarea');` in your function to make the counter work.

So again, let's now try to figure why **your selector is not working** :-)

**Edit:**

Found it!

I **replaced your .closest() with .parent().next()** because I kind of think .closest() was targeting the parent .

```
var shortDescInput = $('nobr:contains("Short Description")').parent().next().find('textarea[title="Short Description"]');
```

Comment: Thanks Gil, I see what you're saying but I don't think that this fiddle is the best representation of what's going on. The page is being output by SharePoint so I (stupidly) only put an extract in the fiddle example. I have confirmed that the selector is definitely getting the right element (the call to the method in pageready works fine) it's just the binding that's not working

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that at least in the fiddle, the `<tr>` wasn't in a `<table>`and so it was removed from the DOM by the browser. Wrapping the `<tr>` in a `<table>` made the fiddle work.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kNkXE/9/

Comment: Sorry that was misleading on my part - this is in a table, but a huge one. I see how it might not have been quite so helpful of me to only post the row I am dealing with. Sorry about that